# How to (SELECT * ) two mysql tables in node.js (express)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

When a user clicks on a post, I want the article to show and also the comments that're saved in a different table. But the code I have only loads the post and not the comments. This is the code I have so far:

```
router.get('/reader', function(req, res){
    //load the post - This works. The post/writing gets loaded
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ID = ?', req.query.id, function(err, result){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    } else{
        //now go through the second table for the comments. The problem is here I think
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_ID = ?', req.query.id, function(err, comm){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            } else{
                //render the page while sending keys and values of the two queries' results arguments
                res.render('reader', {print : result, comment: comm});      
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The two tables have different number of columns so UNION won't work. I tried.

Comment: SELECT * FROM post INNER JOIN table2 ON (post.id = table2.id). Since you are using * then there maybe field name conflicts

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEFT JOIN because your posts may no have comment:

```
SELECT * FROM posts  
LEFT JOIN comments  
ON comments.post_ID = posts.ID
WHERE posts.ID = ?
```